# Hot to update mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

As you will see I am fetching the column, and trying to update column with new data.
`$result2` line is my problem, I don't think I can add `$row[0]` in there. How do I do it?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM items LIMIT 3");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {

    $url=($row[0]);

$rez2 = get_final_url($url);

$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE items SET link = $rez2 WHERE id = $row[0] LIMIT 1")

or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use quotes:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE items SET link = '{$res2}' WHERE id = $row[0]");
```

And it would be ideal to use mysql_escape_string() function.

So:

```
$rez2 = mysql_escape_string(get_final_url($url));
```

Also you're trying to use $row[0] as link and as id. Most likely you want $row[0] element to be an ID, and something like $row[n] where n > 0 to be a link. But if you still want to use link you should query in the following manner:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE items SET link = '$res2' WHERE link = {$row[0]}");
```

And do not forget to escape $row

It is a **good** idea to use mysql_fetch_assoc() function - in this case you'll get an associative array, so you'll be able access elements by sql column names. And as result you could do something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, link FROM items LIMIT 3");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{

   $url=($row['link']);

   $rez2 = mysql_escape_string(get_final_url($url));

   $result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE items SET link = '{$res2}' WHERE id = {$row['id']}")

   or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Also if ID is a primary key you do not need LIMIT 1 in the update query.

Comment: Got it with this '$rez2' not like '{$res2}'
You are reeeaaalll ggooood... Thx a bunch

Answer (score 2):

`$row[0]` is in fact valid in double-quoted strings. I think your problem is a misspelling: first you assign `$rez2` a value and then in the query you use `$res2`.

Comment: Nice catch ;) That was helpfull, but I still get Mysql syntax error:
'://www.newurl.com/test' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

What does `get_final_url($url);` do? If it doesn't surround `link` with quotes, and handle proper string escaping (i.e. [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)), your query won't work.